# Rspec: do a mkdir and then and then pass screenshots to the new directory

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

I've created an `rspec` test where I've created a directory inside of an `it` block and am also taking screenshots of the various states of the test.

It's a form entry I'm testing so the `it` block looks like this:

```
 ...
 it "confirm that a user can successfully sign up" do
    timestamp = Time.now.to_i 
    dir = Dir.mkdir("dir_#{timestamp}")

    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    driver.navigate.to "go/to/url"

    username_field = driver.find_element(id: "user_username")
    username_field.send_keys("user #{timestamp}")
    driver.save_screenshot("./#{dir}/screen_username.png")
    ...
  end
```

So if `timestamp` is 1234, then I'm assuming a directory named `dir_1234` will be created and it will, at some point, put an image inside of it named `screen_username.png` inside of it. But when I run `rspec`, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: driver.save_screenshot("./#{dir}/screen_username.png")

     Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./0/screen_username.png
     ...
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"dir_#{timestamp}" == "./#{dir}` may not be true. Aside from questions about relative paths, `./0/` is not a valid representation of `"dir_#{Time.now.to_i}"`, so you likely have other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dir::mkdir` [always returns](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-mkdir) `0`

```
dir = Dir.mkdir("dir_#{timestamp}") # => 0
```

That's your problem

You can save path to some variable

```
dir_path = File.join(__dir__, "dir_#{timestamp}")

Dir.mkdir(dir_path)

# your code

driver.save_screenshot(File.join(dir_path, "screen_username.png"))
```

Comment: Perfect...thanks much!